# Updating Xcode 4.3 to support ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My Xcode version today is 4.3, so it only supports iOS 5.0, right?. Then I finished my project for my client. What I wanted is for my project to be supported for iOS 5.1, I was thinking of updating my Xcode to 4.3.3, or should I update it to 4.4? to support iOS 5.1. I am really confused right now. 
Would my project be still compatible with the version I am going to update it to, or I'll be changing some codes in my project.

Hope someone will help me, I'm kinda of scared making a mistake. 
Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: FYI, iOs 6.0 and Xcode 4.5 have just been released.

Comment: But I ny mac is lion, i thought its compatible with mountain lion only?

Comment: but wait, i have read the documentation, says that it is still available for osx lion.

Comment: My mistake, it is said in the App Store that required OSX version is 10.7.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see at the [description](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode), Xcode 4.3.3 and Xcode 4.0 both compatible with Lion and support iOs 5.1.

What i want you to know is that from iPhone 5 release it became clear that iOs 6.0 is coming today, probably with the Xcode 4.5 release version to support the latest SDK - it must require Mountain Lion though. And you'll probably lose armv6 support.

Usually you don't have to change any part of the code for the newer SDK support unless you are using something declared as private at header comments or explicitly marked as deprecated.

Comment: so its good to update to xcode 4.0? what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.4.1 from app store and 4.5 from https://developer.apple.com/ on the same machine. I believe you'll have to update to the Xcode supporting the latest SDK in order ro submit the app, correct me if i'm wrong please.

Comment: Just copying the Xcode 4.5 to desktop worked for me, it's smart enough to work together with the older release version, i'm afraid the details are under NDA and you'll have to visit apple devforum: https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios6beta/installation

Comment: but i just wanted for it to support ios 5.1 for now, so what version should it be?

Comment: There're plenty of Xcode versions supporting 5.1 SDK, the latest released is 4.4.1 for the moment and it does support 5.1 SDK together with armv6, i'd use it if you are going to upgrade OSX to ML, if you need to stay with Lion i'd use the latest available Lion version which is 4.3.3.

Comment: updated my xcode to 4.3.3, how will I know if my project is set for 5.1? thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are selecting Base-SDK in the target settings, compiling the project with iphone5.1 as a base SDK means the app is 5.1 compatible (you always need to test the release build on device though).

Answer (score 1):

Update your `XCode` to latest version It would support all lower version as well. Lower version of `XCode` doesn't support the upper **IOS version** than its Compatible **IOS version** but the latest version of `XCode` would support all lower `IOS version`.

I think it is clear enough.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet ... but your're asking about IOS compatible issue so it would better to use latest version of XCode.. If we talk about coding syntax so it may be change .... but only few things not a lot.

Comment: what version are you using? btw, what should be the changes/ or what to do for it to be ready for 5.1, just bulid normally, then it can be done?

Comment: XCode Version 4.2.1 and it doesn't support IOS 5.1.1, but I have another MAC with XCode 4.3.2 and it support IOS 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt Xcode 4.3 support 5.1 Already? are you on Lion? if so, then xcode 4.3 should be supporting 5.1 already.. BTW, xcode 4.3.3 is a lot better and stable version. You shouldn't be worried about it, and have it updated.